# Exporting Illustrator Art Boards without bounding box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have a bunch of art boards that are sized to 88x88 pixels. When I export my art boards, all the images are sized as 88x88, where transparent pixels are surround my actual art work.

Is there a way to export the images and have it not include the surrounding box?

For example, assume all my art boards are 88x88 pixels. In one of them, I have a 40x40 plus sign. In another I have a 40x50 star. When I currently export my images, I get two images that are 88x88 pixels. What I want in one that is 40x40, and another that is 40x50.

Note: I still want to design the icons in a 88x88 grid. Is there a way to easily get these results without resorting to resizing my storyboard to "hug" their artwork?

I am exporting to PNG images.

**Update:** When I attempt to uncheck **Use Artboards** as per [this suggestion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1073/24153), it combines all of my artwork into a single file. This is not what I want. I want 2 separate files in the example above.

I would prefer a solution which doesn't require a script.

All of my artwork is located on a single layer.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6126/export-sublayers-to-png-in-adobe-illustrator

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/how-to-export-only-the-illustration-in-illustrator-cs3

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** If you want to do this without scripts, you could create secondary artboard for each object. That is, design each shape on it's own 88x88 artboard, then create a new artboard on top of the original that fits the exact shape of the object. This will export two images for each object, but one of them will be fit to the shape (the other will be the 88x88 image with the transparent border).

---

*Original Answer:* Do you have access to Photoshop? If so, you could create a new action that "Trim"s each exported image to the exact size of the shape in the PNG Illustrator creates (assuming the surrounding area is transparent/white) and run it on all images Illustrator exports.

Answer (score 0):

The computer can not know magically what you want. We can help it understand by putting each artwork in a different layer/group. Then hide the group you dont want just before export.